# The same value in all rows in Adobe Form

Tags: pdf, abap, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

I created a SAP Adobe form but some fields like `Price` remains the same value for all of the subjects whilst it should print the respective value for each item.

I tried Modify statement but it gave nothing. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some debugging results would be nice (namely, it would be nice to know if your interface and printing program are passing correct information), but without further info I can think of 2 problems that would produce this behavior.

**Error in data binding**: Open design view, select table (left click top left corner), go to object palette, binding tab data binding field has to be set to your table (tablename). Select open Object palette, select binding tab and data binding field should have `$.(fieldname)` and NOT `$.(tablename).(data)[*].(fieldname)` (actual names might be different).

The above means your table element is bound to a table from context and `$.(fieldname)` on a row means that it is bound to a (fieldname) of a row of the table.

Second possible cause is your **printing program or interface providing those details**. Debug your interface, place some breakpoints and see if the internal table that contains row data has correct prices. I'm sure you know how to fix an error in code, if you find out it is an interface / program issue.